# How to compare string and object in Java

Tags: java

I have this code snipped which I use for input validation:

```
public void validaUserID(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException, SQLException {

        int findAccount = 0;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }
        // Initialize a connection to Oracle
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }

        // Convert Object into String
        int findValue = Integer.parseInt(value.toString()); 

        // With SQL statement get all settings and values
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from USERS where USERID = ?");
        ps.setInt(1, findValue);
        try {
            //get data from database        
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                // Put the the data from Oracle into Hash Map
                findAccount = result.getInt("USERID");
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        // Compare the value from the user input and the Oracle data
        if (value.equals(findAccount)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    value + " Session ID is already in use!", null));
        }
    }
```

For some reason the input data is not compared properly with the value in Oracle. What is the proper way to compare the two values?

Comment: "not compared properly" - please be more descriptive.  What input did you use, and what was the resulting behaviour?

Comment: I don't get any output. The proper output should be ".. Session ID is already in use!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're comparing boxed integers. I'd unwrap them (i.e. get them in primitive form) and do `==` instead of `.equals`.

Comment: @user1285928, Glad this helped, but make sure you do some thorough testing before proceeding! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`Objects are compared using` **.equals()**, `and String is an object too, so they also` `have to be compared using .equals().`

eg:

Assume s1 and s2 as String.

s1.equals(s2);

`Primitive variables are compared using` **==**, **as Wrapper are Objects, you need to compare them with .equals()**, `but if you want to compare them using ==`, **then you must first convert them into its Primitive form.**

eg:

Integer a = 5;

int i = new Integer(a);

Answer (score 1):

Well. Answer lies in your code itself.

```
 if (value.equals(findAccount))
```

you can write it instead this way

```
  if (findValue == findAccount))
```

as you have already unwrapped your Object **Value** to primitive **findValue** .

To be more clear, equals() is called on and passed to only objects. You can't compare objects with primitives or vice-versa.